# Limit the number of support vectors in R svm package e1071?

Tags: r, svm

I use the svm function in package e1071. As far as I understand, svm basic functionality can separate two linearly separable classes with an hyperplane (Support vectors). More advanced features allow you to perform numeric regressions and non-linear separation.
When I started testing it on some data I could not understand why the output of the model is a huge set of Support Vectors. 
When I ran it on some very simple test examples I got the same results. Here is an example:

```
X = rnorm(1000)
Y = rnorm(1000)
data = data.frame(X, Y, Z = as.factor(X + Y > 0))
model = svm(formula = Z ~ X + Y, data = data, kernel = "linear")
```

Here is the result:

```
Call:
svm(formula = Z ~ X + Y, data = data, kernel = "linear")


Parameters:
  SVM-Type:  C-classification 
SVM-Kernel:  linear 
  cost:  1 
  gamma:  0.5 

Number of Support Vectors:  102
```

This example is clearly linearly separable by only one Support Vector. If not convinced you can run:

```
ggplot(data, aes(X, Y, col = Z)) + geom_point()
```

What is the meaning of the 102 Support Vectors? Why isn't the number of Support Vectors a parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a distinction between a **soft-margin** and a  **hard-margin** svm. This is controlled by the cost parameter which penalises the degree to which the support vectors are allowed to violate the margin constraint. So, you will get the minimal number of support vectors (which is three and not one) only in the case where your cost parameter is (very) large. Try for example values for the cost parameter > 10000 and you will get three support vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed a huge cost function gives me the desired 3 vectors (I forgot about the margins). Could you elaborate more on why we get more than 3 vectors in the case of a clearly linearly separable variables? Is it because the other vectors produce an objective value for the cost function close enough to the minimal cost?

Comment: With decreasing cost the margin increases with the effect that more and more poins are now lying in the margin area. The more points lie in the margin area, the more support vectors you have.